# Ошибка в программе. С++

Tags: c++

Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl gen(int,int,float (* const)[100])" (?gen@@YAXHHQAY0GE@M@Z) в функции _main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h> 
using namespace std;


void gen(int k, int l, float x[100][100]);
float gen_elem(int k);
int factorial(int k);
void out(int k, int l, float x[100][100]);

int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int s, t;
    float array[100][100];
    do {
        do {
            cout << "\nВведите количество строк массива s (s<=100): ";
            cin >> s;
        } while (s > 100);

        cout << "\nВведите количество столбцов массива t (t<=100): ";
        cin >> t;
    } while (t > 100);

    gen(s, t, array);
    out(s, t, array);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

void gen(int k, int l, int a, int b, float x[100][100]) {
    srand(time(NULL) * 1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            x[i][j] = gen_elem(l);
        }
    }
}

void out(int k, int l, float x[100][100]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            cout << x[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
float gen_elem(int k) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
        sum += (float)k / factorial(i);
    }
    return floor(sum * 10000) / 10000;
}
int factorial(int k) {
    int prod = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        prod *= i;
    }
    return prod;
}
```

Comment: у Вас в предварительном объявлении функция gen имеет 3 параметра, в коде также используется такая же, но чуть ниже реализация функции с 5 параметрами. В этом и вся проблема

Comment: Да, я позже заметил. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: К сожалению, прикрепленный "дубликат" уже слишком большой, но его продолжают лепить не думая

Comment: @KoVadim Скорее наоборот, продолжают лепить дубликаты на тот вопрос не думая и даже не заглядывая в существующий ответ.

Comment: это очевидно для Вас, что это дубликат. Я специально пошел смотреть тот вопрос и скажу, что если не знать, то это абсолютно не очевидно. Там есть близкий случай, когда нет реализации. Но здесь с точки зрения программиста она то как бы есть.

Comment: специально пошел и чуточку отредактировал заголовок